# Compare 2 cells then compare the 2 below

Tags: vba

I am very new to VBA and have been stuck on this for a few days now.

I would like to compare H2 and H3. If equal then turn the cell green , If not equal then turn the cell red.
Once this is complete I would like to do the same for H4 and H5 , then H6 and H7...... all the way down to the last row of data.

Thank you in advance for your help .

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: If you want to do this with VBA where *exactly* are you stuck?  If you have code then it's best to post it, even if it gives errors.  Questions without any code tend to get closed pretty quickly

Comment: Then turn which cell green? `H2` or `H3` or both?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
  Sub ForLoopTest()
  Dim loop_ctr As Integer
  Dim Max As Integer
  Max = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For loop_ctr = 1 To Max
    If loop_ctr Mod 2 = 0 Then
      row_below = loop_ctr + 1
      If Cells(loop_ctr, "H") = Cells(row_below, "H") then
        Cells(loop_ctr, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Cells(row_below, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
      Else
        Cells(loop_ctr, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Cells(row_below, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      End If
    End If
  Next loop_ctr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I still feel like conditional formatting is they way to go here so that it's reactive to values changing in the worksheet, but if you are stuck on VBA as a solution here, something like this should do the trick:

```
Sub greenOrRed()
    Dim lngRow As Long
    For lngRow = 2 To Sheet1.Range("H2").End(xlDown).Row Step 2
        If Sheet1.Range("H" & lngRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("H" & lngRow + 1).Value Then
            Sheet1.Range("H" & lngRow & ":H" & lngRow + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Else 'didn't match
            Sheet1.Range("H" & lngRow & ":H" & lngRow + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next lngRow
End Sub
```

You could also use a For Each loop to walk down the column which makes for some nice to read code. You just have to apply a test for `Mod 2` on the row you are analyzing instead of using the very handy `STEP 2` like in the `For` loop above:

```
Sub greenOrRed()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In Sheet1.Range("H:H").Cells
        If rngCell.Value = "" And rngCell.Row > 1 Then Exit For
        If rngCell.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
            If rngCell.Value = rngCell.Offset(1).Value Then
                rngCell.Resize(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Else
                rngCell.Resize(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        End If
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

And if you really want to condense it you can apply some boolean math to the setting of the `interior.ColorIndex`, but this only works because red and green are 1 colorindex value away from each other. Also the next person that adopts your code will hate you and won't think your nearly as clever as you think you are.

```
Sub greenOrRed()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In Sheet1.Range("H:H").Cells
        If rngCell.Value = "" And rngCell.Row > 1 Then Exit For
        If rngCell.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then rngCell.Resize(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 + Abs(rngCell.Value = rngCell.Offset(1).Value)
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help . I did start with conditional formatting but some times the data will be down to row 20 and some times its down to row 500.

Answer (score 0):

some other ways

another loop approach:

```
Sub CompareCells()
    Dim i As Long
    With Range("H2", Cells(Rows.Count,"H").End(xlUp)) ' reference column H cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
        For i = 1 To .Count Step 2 ' loop through referenced range skipping every other row
            With .Cells(i, 1) ' reference current cell
                .Interior.Color = IIf(.Value2 = .Offset(1).Value2, vbGreen, vbRed) 'set current cell color with respect to below cell content
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

a no-loop approach:

```
Sub CompareCells()
    With Range("H2", Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)) ' reference column H cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
        With .Offset(, 1) ' reference referenced range 1 column to the right offset range. this is a "helpre" column
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(even(row())=row(),1,"""")" ' write 1's every two rows in referenced range
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers) ' reference referenced range "numbered" rows
                .Offset(, -1).Interior.Color = vbRed ' mark referenced range 1 column left offset in red
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=R[1]C[-1],1,"""")" ' signal referenced range cells with 1 if corresponding 1 column to the left offset cell content equals its below cell content
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Offset(, -1).Interior.Color = vbGreen ' turn reference referenced range "numbered" cells color to green
            End With
            .ClearContents ' clear referenced "helper" column
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```